# Constexpr pointer to data member conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, pointer-to-member

GCC 8.2.1 and MSVC 19.20 compile the below code but Clang 8.0.0 and ICC 19.0.1 fail to do so.

```
// Base class.
struct Base {};

// Data class.
struct Data { int foo; };

// Derived class.
struct Derived : Base, Data { int bar; };

// Main function.
int main()
{
  constexpr int Data::* data_p{ &Data::foo };
  constexpr int Derived::* derived_p{ data_p };
  constexpr int Base::* base_p{ static_cast<int Base::*>(derived_p) };

  return (base_p == nullptr);
}
```

The error message with Clang 8.0.0 is the following:

```
case.cpp:16:33: error: constexpr variable 'base_p' must be initialized by a constant expression
  constexpr int Base::* base_p{ static_cast<int Base::*>(derived_p) };
                              ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I noticed that it compiles fine with Clang in two cases:

- remove the constexpr from the last definition
- replace the line `constexpr int Derived::* derived_p{ data_p };` with `constexpr int Derived::* derived_p{ &Derived::bar };` .

Should the constexpr expression (the one that makes Clang and ICC fail) compile?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have filled a bug report [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe GCC and MSVC are correct, this code should compile.

`data_p` points to the member `foo` of `Data`. `derived_p` points to the member `foo` of the `Data` base class subobject of a `Derived` via implicit pointer to member conversion [[conv.mem]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.mem#2).

From [[expr.static.cast]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#12)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type *cv1* `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B` of type *cv2* `T`”, where `B` is a base class of `D`, if *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. […] **If class `B` contains the original member, or is a base or derived class of the class containing the original member, the resulting pointer to member points to the original member.** Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: Although class `B` need not contain the original member, the dynamic type of the object with which indirection through the pointer to member is performed must contain the original member; see [expr.mptr.oper].  — end note ]

As pointed out by @geza in his comment below, the class `Base` is a base class of `Derived`, the latter of which contains the original member `Data::foo` in its `Data` base class subobject (the Note in the quote above would seem to be further evidence in support of this interpretation). Thus, the `static_cast` used to initialize `base_p`is well-formed and has well-defined behavior. The resulting pointer points to the `Data::foo` member of a `Derived` object from the perspective of the `Base` base class subobject of that `Derived` object.

To initialize a `constexpr` object, a constant expression is required [[dcl.constexpr]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#9). Our expression (the result of the `static_cast`) is a core constant expression because there is nothing in [[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2) that would say otherwise. And it is also a constant expression because it is a prvalue that satisfies all the constraints laid out in [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5).

Comment: How about this interpretation? `Base` is a base class of `Derived`. `Derived` contains `foo` (through `Data`). Does containment mean "immediate" containment?

Comment: @YSC _But it is not a bug of the compiler not to reject it_. [dcl.constexpr/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#9) says that the initializer **shall be** a constant expression. How it is not a bug not to diagnose the case when the initializer is not a constant expression?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer you lack context. My comment was outdated.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I agree with you and have deleted my answer, there's no point in fixing it and having two saying the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Note: I think [this sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12.sentence-2) should appear in your answer: this is what links `[expr.static.cast]/12` with `[conv.mem]/2`

Comment: @YSC ironically, I'm not so sure anymore about this by now. I think the wording in the standard is extremely vague here. I was actually considering opening a new question for this. It is imho not clear what it means precisely for a class to "contain" a member. At least, even after extensive search, I was unable to find a clear definition of this in the standard. Would be really happy to know if anyone could find something to back up or contradict our interpretation laid out above…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel [this convinced me](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem#2.sentence-4) "The result refers to the member in D's instance of B."

Comment: @YSC My comment is not correct outside context? Implementations allowed not to emit diagnostic message when a non-constant expression is used when constant is required?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this last line is legal at all, `constexpr` or not.

1. You can convert a pointer to member of a base class to a pointer to member of a derived class, but you can't do the inverse. In relation to conversion between pointers to class instances themselves, pointer-to-member conversions are **contravariant**. This is why you need the `static_cast` to force the compiler to accept this input, even if `Base` has an `int` data member which you could refer to with a pointer to member (see 2. below).

   This makes sense, too: a `Derived` is-a `Base`, hence a `Derived` instance has a sub-object of its parent `Base` class. Now, a pointer to member isn't really a pointer, it's an *offset*, only usable with an address to an actual instance. Any offset within `Base` is also a valid offset within `Derived`, but some offsets within `Derived` aren't valid offsets within `Base`.
2. `Base` has no `int` data member. How would you want to use this pointer to member anyway? The offset it captures might refer to the `Data` suboject within a `Derived` instance, but this should be UB at runtime, and a compiler error at compile time.

So, `gcc` should also reject the snippet, `clang` and `icc` are correct about it.

Comment: @YSC Seems we all needed a few iterations to get things straight in the answers :)

Comment: Are you convinced by the arguments raised by geza, MichaelKenzel and YSC ?